# How to avoid 504 error while import test cases and results into Rally?

Tags: java, api, rally, timeoutexception

I get 504 error sometimes when I am importing test cases & results into rally. I don't want that to happen because the Java application that I created needs to be a part of an automated process.
Are there any suggestions about how I can avoid 504 error? Or is there a way by which the application tries at least 3-4 times before it throws this exception.
I can think of a try/catch block only....

The worst case scenario for me is when the application is adding results to a testset, and 504 exception is thrown. So I now have a testset, containing incomplete list of results.

Comment: How many Test Cases and/or Test Case Results are in the Test Set of concern? Is it possible that other users or processes could be attempting to add Test Case Results to a particular Test Case at the same time as your automation runs?

Comment: ~700 testcases. No, I don't believe anyone else do anything with those test cases.

Comment: The Java application takes on average 4000secs to do the job and this 504 error occurs once per week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend opening a Case with [Rally Support](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/help.sp?pp=contact). The gateway timeouts may not be an issue with your integration code. Support has tools they can use to look at the server-side response for the requests you are making and help identify any bottle necks. It's probably a dialog best handled through that channel.